# when run the testng through command prompt getting system can not find the file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have class files which are compiled in `C:\Users\Chandrasekaran\eclipse-workspace\DemoTestForHealenium\target\classes`

testng and jcommander Jar files and `testng.xml` is present in `C:\Users\Chandrasekaran\eclipse-workspace\DemoTestForHealenium`

```
java -cp "C:\Users\Chandrasekaran\eclipse-workspace\DemoTestForHealenium\target\classes;C:\Users\Chandrasekaran\eclipse-workspace\DemoTestForHealenium\testng.jar;C:\Users\Chandrasekaran\eclipse-workspace\DemoTestForHealenium\jcommander.jar" org.testng.TestNG -testngxml C:\Users\Chandrasekaran\eclipse-workspace\DemoTestForHealenium\testng.xml
```

when I run, getting The system cannot find the file specified

```
C:\Users\Chandrasekaran\eclipse-workspace\DemoTestForHealenium>java -cp "C:\Users\Chandrasekaran\eclipse-workspace\DemoTestForHealenium\target\classes;C:\Users\Chandrasekaran\eclipse-workspace\DemoTestForHealenium\testng.jar;C:\Users\Chandrasekaran\eclipse-workspace\DemoTestForHealenium\jcommander.jar" org.testng.TestNG -testngxml C:\Users\Chandrasekaran\eclipse-workspace\DemoTestForHealenium\testng.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Chandrasekaran\eclipse-workspace\DemoTestForHealenium\-testngxml (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:156)
        at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:246)
        at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:298)
        at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:350)
        at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:980)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:992)
        at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1326)
        at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1294)
```

when I run testng.xml directly from eclipse it is working but run from command prompt it is not working..

```
[2023-07-04 19:00:34,822] ERROR in app: Exception on /process [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\20722\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\20722\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\20722\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\20722\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "TodayBackup.py", line 55, in process
    bot_response += get_branches()
  File "TodayBackup.py", line 90, in get_branches
    process = subprocess.run(["git", "branch", "--list", "--remote"], cwd=repo_path, capture_output=True, text=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2023 19:00:34] "←[35m←[1mPOST /process HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is, on your CWD, it is searching for a file named `-testngxml`, hence the `FileNotFoundException`.

Since this is the default behavior, there is no `-testngxml` flag for TestNG.

So, removing the redundant `-testngxml` will fix your issue.

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng) for more information

Comment: removing that testngxml it shows 0 runs.. even though the testng.xml has classes which is having more tests